# Web scraping according to user input form data

Tags: python-3.x, forms, web, post, web-scraping

I surprised when I have asked to tell logic behind the website to scrape https://www.astroyogi.com/kundli/kundli-matching.I didnt How can I fill the details and goes to next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways. First of all, you can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control your web browser, fill out forms and then click on the button. Secondly, you can also use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library to send the necessary data using POST request. Finally, you can also use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) as a library to help you scrape websites.

Comment: Some time ago I recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzvA6aOkH5I) how to use selenium on Facebook page. You can view it and do what you need in a similar way. English subtitles are available in the movie.